# Sprites not drawing in SFML - Being stored and retrieved from a vector

Tags: c++, vector, sfml

I'm making a scrolling space shooter for fun using SFML.

My idea for implementing the bullets was to have a vector of the following struct:

```
struct bullet
{
    sf::Sprite sprite;
    char frame;
};
```

And have a new instance of this struct added to a vector every time the user presses a key. My idea was that the frame value for each object in the vector could be updated and then I could use a switch statement to change the textureRect that applies to each projectile based on how far they were through the animation sequence.

This, however, does not work, and when space is pressed nothing is drawn. The event is being triggered, but I cannot figure out where the problem lies as there are no errors. Everything else works perfectly.

Shoot function:

```
void shoot(sf::Texture texture, std::vector<bullet>& onScreenBullets, sf::Sprite fighter)
{
    bullet newBullet;
    sf::Sprite bulletSprite = newBullet.sprite;
    bulletSprite.setTexture(texture);
    bulletSprite.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(48,0,4,4));
    bulletSprite.setPosition(fighter.getPosition().x + 6, fighter.getPosition().y + 6);
    newBullet.frame = 0;
    onScreenBullets.push_back(newBullet);
}
```

Function call:

```
while(window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if(event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            {
                window.close();
            }

            if(event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed)
            {
                if(event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Return && play == false)
                {
                    play = true;
                    clock.restart();
                }

                if(event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Space && play == true)
                {
                    shoot(texture,onScreenBullets,fighter);
                }
            }
        }
```

Logic for animating the projectiles:

```
for(int i = 0; i < onScreenBullets.size(); i++)
            {
                currentBullet = onScreenBullets.at(i).sprite;
                switch(onScreenBullets[i].frame)
                {
                    case 0:
                        currentBullet.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(48,4,4,8));
                        break;
                    case 15:
                        currentBullet.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(48,12,4,8));
                        break;
                    case 30:
                        currentBullet.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(48,4,4,8));
                        break;
                    case 45:
                        currentBullet.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(48,12,4,8));
                        break;
                    case 60:
                        onScreenBullets.at(i).frame = 0;
                        break;
                }

                currentBullet.move(0, -1*(projectileSpeed + scrollSpeed));
                window.draw(currentBullet);
                onScreenBullets.at(i).frame++;

                if(!currentView.intersects(currentBullet.getGlobalBounds()));
                {
                    onScreenBullets.erase(onScreenBullets.begin() + i);
                }
            }
```

Full source:

```
#include<SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>

void rollLeft(sf::Sprite& s, sf::RenderWindow& rw, int frame, char& rollDir, bool& rstatus)
{
    switch(frame)
    {
        case 0:
            s.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(32,0,8,16));
            s.move(sf::Vector2f(-32.0f,0.0f));
            rw.draw(s);
            rw.display();
            break;

        case 4:
            s.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(16,0,16,16));
            s.move(sf::Vector2f(-64.0f,0.0f));
            rw.draw(s);
            rw.display();
            break;

        case 8:
            s.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(40,0,8,16));
            s.move(sf::Vector2f(-32.0f,0.0f));
            rw.draw(s);
            rw.display();
            break;

        case 12:
            s.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(0,0,16,16));
            s.move(sf::Vector2f(-64.0f,0.0f));
            rw.draw(s);
            rw.display();
            rollDir = 'N';
            rstatus = false;
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}

void rollRight(sf::Sprite& s, sf::RenderWindow& rw, int frame, char& rollDir, bool& rstatus)
{
    switch(frame)
    {
        case 0:
            s.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(40,0,8,16));
            s.move(sf::Vector2f(32.0f,0.0f));
            rw.draw(s);
            rw.display();
            break;

        case 4:
            s.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(16,0,16,16));
            s.move(sf::Vector2f(64.0f,0.0f));
            rw.draw(s);
            rw.display();
            break;

        case 8:
            s.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(32,0,8,16));
            s.move(sf::Vector2f(32.0f,0.0f));
            rw.draw(s);
            rw.display();
            break;

        case 12:
            s.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(0,0,16,16));
            s.move(sf::Vector2f(64.0f,0.0f));
            rw.draw(s);
            rw.display();
            rollDir = 'N';
            rstatus = false;
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}

void init(sf::Text& text,sf::Sprite& fighter,sf::Sprite& barLeft,sf::Sprite&     barMiddle,sf::Sprite& barRight,sf::Sprite& marker,sf::RectangleShape& background1,
            sf::RectangleShape& background2,sf::View& view,sf::RenderWindow& window)
{
    text.setPosition(20,240);
    fighter.setPosition(304,448);
    barLeft.setPosition(72,10);
    barMiddle.setPosition(80,10);
    barRight.setPosition(560,10);
    marker.setPosition(88,10);
    background1.setPosition(0,0);
    background2.setPosition(0,-480);
    view.setCenter(320,240);
    window.setView(view);
             }

struct bullet
{
    sf::Sprite sprite;
    char frame;
};

void shoot(sf::Texture texture, std::vector<bullet>& onScreenBullets, sf::Sprite fighter)
{
    bullet newBullet;
    sf::Sprite bulletSprite = newBullet.sprite;
    bulletSprite.setTexture(texture);
    bulletSprite.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(48,0,4,4));
    bulletSprite.setPosition(fighter.getPosition().x + 6, fighter.getPosition().y + 6);
    newBullet.frame = 0;
    onScreenBullets.push_back(newBullet);
}

int main()
{
    int frame = 0;
    char rollDir = 'N';
    bool roll,move,play,activeBackground = false;
    int timeLimit = 10000;
    int scrollSpeed = 2;
    int projectileSpeed = 5;
    std::vector<bullet> onScreenBullets;
    sf::Sprite currentBullet;
    sf::FloatRect currentView;

    sf::Time time;
    int timeInt;
    sf::Clock clock;

    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(640,480), "Test Window");
    window.setFramerateLimit(60);

    sf::Texture texture;
    if(!texture.loadFromFile("spritesheet.png"))
    {
        std::cout << "Error loading texture from file";
    }

    sf::Font font;
    if(!font.loadFromFile("font.ttf"))
    {
        std::cout << "Error loading font from file";
     }

    sf::Text text;
    text.setFont(font);
    text.setString("Press ENTER to start");
    text.setCharacterSize(24);
    text.setColor(sf::Color::White);

    sf::Sprite fighter;
    fighter.setTexture(texture);
    fighter.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(0,0,16,16));
    fighter.setScale(sf::Vector2f(2,2));

    sf::Sprite barLeft,barRight,barMiddle;
    barLeft.setTexture(texture);
    barRight.setTexture(texture);
    barMiddle.setTexture(texture);

    barLeft.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(0,16,8,16));
    barRight.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(39,16,8,16));
    barMiddle.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(9,16,30,16));

    barMiddle.setScale(sf::Vector2f(16,1));

    sf::Sprite marker;
    marker.setTexture(texture);
    marker.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(0,0,16,16));
    marker.setRotation(90);

    sf::RectangleShape background1(sf::Vector2f(640,480));
    background1.setTexture(&texture);
    background1.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(0,32,640,480));

    sf::RectangleShape background2(sf::Vector2f(640,480));
    background2.setTexture(&texture);
    background2.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(0,32,640,480));

    sf::View view(sf::FloatRect(0,0,640,480));
    window.setView(view);

    while(window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while(window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if(event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            {
                window.close();
            }

            if(event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed)
            {
                if(event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Return && play == false)
                {
                    play = true;
                    clock.restart();
                }

                if(event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Space && play == true)
                {
                    shoot(texture,onScreenBullets,fighter);
                }
            }
        }

        if(!play)
        {
            window.clear(sf::Color::Black);
            window.draw(text);
                init(text,fighter,barLeft,barMiddle,barRight,marker,background1,background2,view,window);
            window.display();
        }

        if(play)
        {

            move = false;

            if(!roll)
            {
                if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::W))
                {
                    fighter.move(sf::Vector2f(0.0f,-4.0f));
                    move = true;
                }

                if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::S))
                {
                    fighter.move(sf::Vector2f(0.0f,4.0f));
                    move = true;
                }

                if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::A))
                {
                    fighter.move(sf::Vector2f(-4.0f,0.0f));
                    move = true;
                }

                if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::D))
                {
                    fighter.move(sf::Vector2f(4.0f,0.0f));
                    move = true;
                }

                if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::A) &&     sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::LShift) && rollDir == 'N')
                {
                    frame = 0;
                    rollDir = 'L';
                    roll = true;
                }

                if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::D) &&     sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::LShift) && rollDir == 'N')
                {
                    frame = 0;
                    rollDir = 'R';
                    roll = true;
                }
            }

            switch(rollDir)
            {
                case 'L':
                    rollLeft(fighter,window,frame,rollDir,roll);
                    break;

                case 'R':
                    rollRight(fighter,window,frame,rollDir,roll);
                    break;
            }

            window.clear(sf::Color::Black);
            window.draw(background1);
            window.draw(background2);

            time = clock.getElapsedTime();
            timeInt = time.asMilliseconds();

            view.move(0,-1*scrollSpeed);
            window.setView(view);

            fighter.move(0,-1*scrollSpeed);
            window.draw(fighter);

            currentView.left = view.getCenter().x - view.getSize().x / 2;
            currentView.top = view.getCenter().y - view.getSize().y / 2;
            currentView.width = view.getSize().x;
            currentView.height = view.getSize().y;

            for(int i = 0; i < onScreenBullets.size(); i++)
            {
                currentBullet = onScreenBullets.at(i).sprite;
                switch(onScreenBullets[i].frame)
                {
                    case 0:
                        currentBullet.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(48,4,4,8));
                        break;
                    case 15:
                        currentBullet.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(48,12,4,8));
                        break;
                    case 30:
                        currentBullet.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(48,4,4,8));
                        break;
                    case 45:
                        currentBullet.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(48,12,4,8));
                        break;
                    case 60:
                        onScreenBullets.at(i).frame = 0;
                        break;
                }

                currentBullet.move(0, -1*(projectileSpeed + scrollSpeed));
                window.draw(currentBullet);
                onScreenBullets.at(i).frame++;

                if(!currentView.intersects(currentBullet.getGlobalBounds()));
                {
                    onScreenBullets.erase(onScreenBullets.begin() + i);
                }
            }

            barLeft.move(0,-1*scrollSpeed);
            barRight.move(0,-1*scrollSpeed);
            barMiddle.move(0,-1*scrollSpeed);
            window.draw(barLeft);
            window.draw(barRight);
            window.draw(barMiddle);

            if(int (view.getCenter().y - 240) % 480 == 0)
            {
                if(!activeBackground)
                {
                    activeBackground = true;
                    background1.move(0,-960);
                } else {
                    activeBackground = false;
                    background2.move(0,-960);
                }
            }

            marker.move(480.0f/(timeLimit/1000)/60,-1*scrollSpeed);
            window.draw(marker);

            text.move(0,-1*scrollSpeed);

            if(timeInt >= timeLimit+250)
            {
                play = false;
                text.setString("End");
            }

            window.display();
            frame++;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: make a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't be completly sure where the problem is but I think there are a few things that are problematic:

I erased a bit to make this short:

```
void shoot(sf::Texture texture) { //creates a copy of your texture you pass

bulletSprite.setTexture(texture); //actually takes the address of your texture 

(setTexture(sf::Texture&)) <-- that's how the method probably looks like


onScreenBullets.push_back(newBullet); // I think this is okay since newBullet is bein copied into the vector so when the object runs out of scope it doesn't matter but

// here your texture object is gone now and the address your Sprite holds is not valid anymore
}
```

Ooookay,

the shoot method is the problem

```
    void shoot(sf::Texture& texture, std::vector<bullet>& onScreenBullets, sf::Sprite& fighter)
    {
        bullet newBullet;
        sf::Sprite bulletSprite = newBullet.sprite; // this makes no sense
        bulletSprite.setTexture(texture); // you set the texture to the local Sprite object
        bulletSprite.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(48,0,4,4)); // and this as well and the next line as well
        bulletSprite.setPosition(fighter.getPosition().x + 6, fighter.getPosition().y + 6);
        newBullet.frame = 0;
        onScreenBullets.push_back(newBullet); //but here you push back your struct and the sprite in the struct
//That you haven't used at all :O
}
```

do something like this :

```
void shoot(sf::Texture& texture, std::vector<bullet>& onScreenBullets, sf::Sprite& fighter)
    {
bullet newBullet;
newBullet.sprite.setTexture(texture);
newBullet.sprite.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(48,0,4,4));
newBullet.sprite.setPosition(fighter.getPosition().x + 6, fighter.getPosition().y - 6);
// btw. above your "fighter" the y-position is lower so if the bullet is supposed to spawn above your fighter you have to go -6 and then keep subtracting from y to make it go up
newBullet.frame = 0;
onScreenBullets.push_back(newBullet);
}
```

the setTexture method:
http://sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1Sprite.php#a3729c88d88ac38c19317c18e87242560

A couple other thinks I noticed:

1. make your "frame" inside the struct an int (it won't work with a char)
2. your intersects method is probably broken you just erase the bullets instantly (comment it out to see your bullets fly)
3. Overall you copy the bullet objects a lot and stuff like that. I think you're into something that requires a bit more basic understanding. Sorry ;x

Comment: I'll try passing the texture by reference to the function then.

Comment: that's a great idea ;) since you're already on it also pass the "fighter" sprite as reference (no need to copy it everytime ;))

Comment: Didn't make a difference.

Comment: your onScreenBullets stays empty after a shot was added   Imma try to figure out why ;)

Comment: Ah you're right; it was because I was creating a completely new sprite rather than invoking the methods on the sprite in the struct. Thanks

Comment: finalllyyyyy ^.^ I'll go have breakfast have a nice day